# Determine formula $h(t) = a +b \cos(c t)$ given time in minutes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A ferriswheel is 135 meters high at its top and takes 30 minutes to complete its round. The height of a cabin can be written as $h(t) = a + b \cos(c t)$. Determine $a$, $b$ and $c$.
So:

- $t = 0, h(t) = 0$
- $t = 7.5, h(t) = 67.5$
- $t = 15, h(t) = 135$
- $t = 22.5, h(t) = 67.5$
- $t = 30, h(t) = 0$

**My approach**

When $t=0$, then height is $0$, so: $0 = 135 - b \cos(c * 0)$, since $\cos(c * 0) = 1$ for any $c$, I thought $a = 135, b = - 135$ would be an appropriate starting point. Satisfying: $0= 135 - 135 \cos(0c)$

When $t=7.5$, then height is $67.5$, so: $67.5 = 135 - 135 \cos(c * 7.5)$ and $\cos(c * 7.5)$ must be $\frac{1}{2}$. $\cos\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$, so $7.5c = \frac{\pi}{3}, c = \frac{\pi}{22.5}$. Now it starts to get iffy. When $t = 15$, $\cos(15c) = $, so $15c = \frac{\pi}{2}, c =\frac{\pi}{30}$

A contradiction: Clearly this model is wrong :)

**What now?**

When $t = 0, 0 = a + b \cos(0)$, so it seems clear to me that $0 = a + b, a = -b$ and vice versa.

When $t = 30, 135 = a + b \cos(30c)$, seems to me I really need 135 in there somewhere. Probably I'm wrong. What would be a good way to approach this (please refrain from giving an entire answer).

Thanks to @Shuri2060's answer I can say $a = 67.5$.

Should I write out the entire answer or leave it for others to figure out $b$ and $c$ on their own if they're interested?

Comment: I don't think $a$ is 135. When $b\cos(ct)$ is positive, $h$ exceeds 135.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the minimum and maximum of $h$. That would be $a+b$ and $a-b$ (when $\cos (ct) = ±1$).

You don't know which is which, as it depends on the sign of $b$. But sketch the graph of $y=\cos x$ and note that $h$ initially increases as the cabin starts at the bottom at $t=0$.

You can now solve for $a$ and $b$ as you know $h_\min = 0$ and $h_\max = 135$.

Comment: Got it, I'll edit my question to supply the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $a=\frac{135}{2}$, $b=-\frac{135}{2}$, and c= $\frac{\pi}{15}$.

I had an identical problem in the course that I'm taking. It's important to note, that $c$ is supposed to be expressed in radians, according to the text of the problem I was given.

With this in mind, it is best to solve for $c$ first, since we at least know it is some amount of radians which when multiplied by $t$ indicates the height at a given time.

The question is how many radians to give $c$ and why. I didn't know at first. But I was told to multiply 30 (i.e. the time it takes for one complete cycle of the wheel) times $c$. This gives the radians for one complete cycle. The calculation is $30c=2\pi$. ($2\pi$ is equal to 360 degrees.)

This is an equation, so you have to simplify it. You have to divide the left side by 30 and the right side by 30. This gives you $c=\frac{2\pi}{30}$, which then simplifies further to $\frac{\pi}{15}$.

I'm still struggling to figure out why you multiply by 30. Why not 15, i.e. the time it takes to reach the highest point? If I'm not mistaken, this also works out to $\frac{\pi}{15}$. Nobody was able to explain that to me. Anyway, c is solved for $\frac{\pi}{15}$.

Now you can start working on the $a$ and $b$ values.

We know that $h(0) = 0: a + b = 0$, and  $h(15): a - b = 135$. 15 represents the number of minutes for the wheel to make half of a full cycle. So, when $t = 0$, $cos(ct) = cos(0), which = 1$, so $h(0): a + b cos(0) = a + b$. The second is because when $t = 15$, $ct$ = $\frac{\pi}{15}$15 = $\pi$, and $cos(\pi) = -1$, so $h(15): a + b cos(-1) = a - b$.

Now we have a system of equations, which you can solve for $a$ and $b$ by using 'addition of linear equations':

$\;\;\ a+b=0\\
+\underline{a-b=135}$

=$2a=135$

=$a=\frac{135}{2}$

Then you have to substitute $a$ with $\frac{135}{2}$ into $a+b=0$. When you do and simplify everything, you get $b=-\frac{135}{2}$. Then you do the same for the second equation and find that $b=-\frac{135}{2}$, so it must be true.

If my explanation is wrong, please let me know.